# Emacs autocomplete doesn't update C++ suggestions

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I have autocomplete set up for Emacs, and for elisp, it works perfectly fine.  I have it set up to use ctags for completion in C++ files and the suggestions appear as expected.  However, it doesn't update suggestions as I type.  For example, if I type:

```
vector<string> s;
s.
```

it suggests 'at'.  However, if I add to it so that it looks like:

```
vector<string> s;
s.push
```

the suggestion doesn't update and still displays 'at' as the first suggestion, rather than 'push_back'.

I am an Emacs novice and have virtually no elisp knowledge, and was wondering how I can configure autocomplete so that it updates suggestions for C++ as I type.